# What is the best way to know when the UIViewController above me in the stack has been popped?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I have a `UIViewController` that manages the display of some data. When the user wants to edit this data I push an edit `UIViewController` onto the stack. When the user is finished editing the top view controller is popped off the stack. What is the most elegant way to know that I need to update my display after the edit view is popped off?

I thought that I might be able to put the content update code into the `viewDidLoad` method of my data view, but this method isn't always called when my view displays, especially not when I'm navigating down the view stack.

I also considered setting up my data view controller as a delegate for the `UINavigationController` and wait for `– navigationController:didShowViewController:animated:` to be called, my concern is that there may be other view controllers that need to be notified when they're displayed and it will turn into a minor headache managing which controller should be receiving the `didShowViewController` message.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think viewWillAppear will do the trick.

Otherwise your edit view controller could call a new method of delegate pointing to your parent controller. In there, you can update the data model and display. For instance:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    if ([delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(editEntryByTitle:)])
        [delegate performSelector:@selector(editEntryByTitle:) withObject: textField.text];
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    return YES;
}
```